# IP Addresses with boot2docker

Tags: wso2, boot2docker, kitematic, wso2-governance-registry

I'm attempting to install WSO2 GREG in a docker container using docker-toolbox (Kitematic and boot2docker) on my Macbook Pro.

The application is up and running just fine but it does some redirects during login that the networking layers in Kitematic->boot2docker seem to confuse.

Here are the details:

1. My guest systems IP is 192.168.99.100. Accessing the application via that IP works just fine.
2. When I attempt to login, the app redirects my browser to a URL using the containers IP (172.17.0.2) rather than the guest's IP (192.168.99.100). Unfortunately, the container IP is not accessible to my host computer and the redirect fails with a page not accessible.

I've updated the configuration file for the app to point to the Guest OS's IP in what I believe is the relevant configuration file (repository/conf/identity/sso-idp-config.xml).

I have updated the carbon.xml file to reference the Guest IP (192.168.99.100) but the application still seems to start on the containers IP.

```
[2016-01-28 18:43:36,737]  INFO  {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Governance Center Publisher Default Context : https://172.17.0.2:9449/publisher
```

So I think there are two possible answers I'm looking for:

1. How can I configure GREG to startup and reference the guest IP rather than the container's IP?
2. How can I configure boot2docker or my local machine to forward requests on the containers IP as requests to the guest VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about **GREG**, but in IS and AM that happens if you are not defining a particular IP/Hostname in <HostName> and     <MgtHostName> in `repository/conf/carbon.xml` (they are commented out by default)

Comment: The <MgtHostName> I missed somehow. Now that I have updated both the Host and MgtHost it seems to be working. Thanks.